# Sampling without Replacement Probability with 2 different color marbles.

Tags: probability

A container contains 4 Red marbles and 2 Green Marbles. I pull out each marble one at a time, without putting an marbles back in. X is a random variable that is the number of red marbles before pulling out a Green. Y is a random variable that is the number of green marbles that I draw out in the first three tries.

What is the Range of X and Y?

Calculate the probability mass function of P(x) for X? (Make a table of the  probability distribution for X)

Is {X ≤ 1} or {Y ≤ 1} likely?

---

I figured the range of X is {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} since you cant have more than 4 marbles coming before Green and for Y is {0, 1, 2} since you're only limited to two green marbles.

For the second question would P(X = 0) = Pr(GGRRRR) since no Reds come before Green and P(X = 1) = Pr(RGGRRRR), P(X = 2) = Pr(RRGGRRR) and so on. I'm not sure how to find these values, since these events aren't independent I would have to make a tree diagram with 6 sets of "generations" until I have an outcome space of 6 marbles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the ranges okay.  Your reasoning is correct.

The event of $X=0$ is that of drawing one green marble first, and then *any* arrangement of the rest.   There are two of the six marbles which could be drawn first that gives this event (ie: the green ones).$$\mathsf P(X=0)~=~ \frac 2 6$$

The event of $X=1$ is that of drawing a red marble first, a green second, and then any arrangement of the rest.$$\mathsf P(X=1)~=~\frac{4}{6}{\cdot}\frac{2}{5}~=~\frac{4}{15}$$

And so on... although you only need $\mathsf P(X\leq 1)~=~\mathsf P(X=0)+\mathsf P(X=1)$.

---

Can you now find $\mathsf P(Y\leq 1)$ the probability of drawing *at most* one green marble *somewhere* among the first three marbles drawn?